# Invalid Bundle - One or more dynamic libraries are not present in the dylib search path

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, testflight, dylib

I have problem when uploading new build to TestFlight. I get error:

> Invalid Bundle - One or more dynamic libraries that are referenced by
>   your app are not present in the dylib search path.

I know there are many topics that are about this error but nothing help me so far. I am using Carthage for 3rd party libraries. I tried:

- Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries - set to either YES or NO. Both doesn't work.
- Check `.ipa` file with `otool -L` and all libraries from Carthage were there
- I was thinking that problem could be with linking `libz.tbd` and `libsc++.tbd` but I removed them and it didn't help
- When I disable bitcode when creating build app gets successfully to TestFlight but app is crashing at start

Anyone can help me with this? Thanks

Comment: You have to remove Carthage library. I was faced same error before. I removed all carthage library and install again from pod. Hope this may help you!

Comment: I like Carthage and I use it in more projects and in other projects no problem with Carthage.

Comment: I have used TPKeyboard and SVProgressHud library as carthage. May be that library has some issue. If you used any of above library then you can try my suggestion. My be help!